# Python class instantiation in the way Stripe does it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering, I have a random desire to understand how Stripe instantiates its classes in such a neat way:

e.g.,

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division, print_function

import os

import stripe


stripe.api_key = os.environ.get("STRIPE_SECRET_KEY")

print("Attempting charge...")

resp = stripe.Charge.create(
    amount=200,
    currency="usd",
    card="tok_visa",
    description="customer@gmail.com",
)

print("Success: %r" % (resp))
```

I'm working in a similar vein of class inheritance, however, I can only get the following to work:

```
resp = myexamplepackage.Quantity().list()
```

i.e., I have to call the Quantity class, `Quantity()`, before I can utilize class methods...

My `Quantity()` class would look something like this:

```
class Quantity(
    APIClient,
    ListAPIMixin
):

    OBJECT_NAME = "Quantity"

    def __init__(
        self,
        *args,
        **kwargs
    ):
        super(Quantity, self).__init__()

    def list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(Quantity, self).list(
            path='{}/{}'.format(self.realm, self.resource)
        )
```

N.B. the `list()` call is passed onto the ListAPIMixin class but I'm not sure that is important here.

I've toyed with numerous ways within the **init**() call, but I'm not sure this is possible without some extra heavy lifting:

```
    def __init__(
        self,
        *args,
        **kwargs
    ):
        super(Quantity, self).__init__()
        self()
```

```
    def __init__(
        self,
        *args,
        **kwargs
    ):
        super(Quantity, self)()
```

But nothing seems to be working exactly as stripe seems to be able to achieve.

Comment: most likely the `create` method is decorated with `@classmethod`, you don't need to instantiate a class before calling a method

Comment: @rioV8 Ok so I tried that but I get AttributeErrors, e.g., `AttributeError: type object 'Quantity has no attribute 'base_url'` The base_url attribute belongs to the APIClient class...

Comment: @rioV8 Any ideas on what is causing the attribute error?

Comment: never use `super` for multiple inheritance, better never use `super`, use the fully qualified  method `ListAPIMixin.list(self, ......)`. Because `list` has a `self` parameter you **NEED** an instantiation of `Quantity`

Answer (score 0):

`stripe.Charge` inherits its `create` function from [`stripe.api_resources.abstract.creatable_api_resource.CreateableAPIResource`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/blob/master/stripe/api_resources/abstract/createable_api_resource.py#L7), and there, it is decorated with `@classmethod`. This decorator allows the decorated method to be called without an existing instance of the class, but rather the class object itself instead. A good explanation with examples can be found at [StackAbuse](https://stackabuse.com/pythons-classmethod-and-staticmethod-explained/).